# How to get an access token using Azure AD b2c via C# code?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Azure Active Directory B2C user password authentication
What is the way to get `Azure AD b2c` auth token?
Trying to get access token with Microsoft.Identity.Client.
Code:

```
var appId = "<applicationId/ClientId>";
var b2cAuthority = "https://<applicationUrl>/tfp/<applicationUrl>/<userFlow>";
var b2cScopes = new[] { "<readScope>" };
var tenantId = "<tenantId>";
var userLogin = "<login>";
var userPassword = "<password>";
SecureString securePassword = new NetworkCredential("", userPassword).SecurePassword;
var msalPublicClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
   .Create(appId)
   .WithB2CAuthority(b2cAuthority)
   .WithTenantId(tenantId)               
   .Build();
AuthenticationResult authResult = await msalPublicClient
    .AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(b2cScopes, userLogin, securePassword)
    .WithClaims("emails")  
    .ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

On .ExecuteAsync() exception is thrown: `AADB2C90108: The orchestration step '1' does not specify a CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId when one was expected`
Is there any way to fix this?
We don't want to change any default policies to fix it.

Comment: Are you using custom policies? ROPC flow?

Comment: @rbrayb no custom policies

Comment: @VladyslavFurdak, did you mange to get it working? I have exactly the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your user flow or policy. You're going to have to fix that. Your code is fine.

Comment: I have the same code and the same issue. Only user flow, no custom policy. And similar login works for Swagger/SPA app.